# Database transaction in a ejb transaction

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, persistence

For a database transaction called in an ejb transaction, the ejb transaction must wait for other concurrent database transactions in other ejb instances on the particular entity table to finish before preceding?

Comment: Like the removed quesiton, this is a [shopping list question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad). You should split it.

Comment: Definitely should split it, there are 4 kinds of EJBs, each with their own distinct lifecycles, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giplj.html. Then there are 6 different transactions related annotations that define the transnational behavior, see http://tomee.apache.org/transaction-annotations.html. Sigh, the list goes on, might as well go read the spec, then come back with a more specific question, see http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/

Answer (score 0):

This is not covered by the EJB specification or even by EJB implementations.  Instead, the locking/blocking behavior for transactions is controlled by the isolation level setting of the JDBC connection and the database being accessed.